# Reading from a file in bash without using the standard loop - non-typical use case

Tags: bash, file, fopen

I am familiar with the following code to read every line of a file and perform some command.

```
while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
done < filename
```

The above loop is driven by each line in the file with a block of operations performed in the loop.

I have a script with nested loops that spawn and control threads.  I want to be able to pull a line at a time from the file by command in the loop instead of having the line frame the loop.  For example, in other languages, there would be an `fopen()` then an `fread()` and an `fclose()` toward the end of the program to clean up.  Is there an equivalent in bash?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and bash 4.4.20

Comment: If you are open to other tools, you can use `sed`, `awk`... for that. Otherwise, you can encapsulate that functionality in a `bash` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, you can open a file using the 'exec' command. Assuming no other input files, you can redirect stdin. If stdin is used for something else, consider opening the file on a different file descriptor (3, 4, ...). You can not use 0, 1 and 2 and they are already associated with stdin/stdout/stderr.

Using stdin:

```
exec < filename

read ...
if [ ... ] ; then
    read ...
fi

# Close
exec <&-
```

Using a different file descriptor

```
exec 3<filename

read -u3 ...
if [ ... ] ; then
    read -u3 ...
fi
exec 3<&-
```

Note that unlike other environment, the code has to choose a distinct file descriptor to use, which can be tricky if there are many files to open at the same time. Better solution, based on @wjandrea comment

```
exec {myfile}<filename

read -u$myfile ...
if [ ... ] ; then
    read -u$myfile ...
fi
exec $myfile<&-
```

Comment: *"the code has to choose a distinct file descriptor to use"* - You can use a named descriptor for that: `exec {in}<filename; read -u $in ...; exec {in}<&-`

Comment: @wjandrea Good to learn about new features. I do not have this in my Mint 19 (bas 4.4). When was this added? - can you put a link to it ?

Comment: That's weird, I'm using Bash 4.3 on Ubuntu... It's documented here: [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html). *"Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be preceded by a word of the form `{varname}`."*

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for the pointer. Just found it. It's is easy to miss - there was no  single example that demonstrate this redirection. Revising my answer ...